# Is there a single continuous function satisfy all these properties?

Tags: functions, derivatives

I'm finding one $C^2$, non-decreasing function $f$: $[0, 1] \to \mathbb{R}$ that

\begin{align}
f'(0) &= 0, \\
f'(0.5) &= \max f'(x) \text{ } \forall \text{ } x \in [0, 1] \\ 
f'(1) &= 0, \text{ and} \\
f''(0.5) &= 0. \\ 
\end{align}

A [Gaussian function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_function) with $b = 0.5$ would be my 2nd choice of $f'(x)$ but I wish it reaches, not only approaches $0$ at both ends. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about $f(x) = \cos \pi \left( x-1\right)$?

Comment: Nice starting point.

Answer (score 0):

After lots of trials, for those who came later, I came up with a more general function $f$: $[a, b] \to [c, d]$:

$$f(x) = \left(\left(\dfrac{x - a}{b - a}\right) - \sin\left(2 \pi \left(\dfrac{x - a}{b - a}\right) \right)/(2 \pi)\right) \times (d - c) + c$$

which satisfy all these properties:

\begin{align}
f'(a) &= 0, \\
f'(0.5(a + b)) &= \max f'(x) \text{ } \forall \text{ } x \in [a, b], \\
f'(b) &= 0, \text{ and} \\
f''(0.5(a + b)) &= 0.
\end{align}

Comment: Shouldn’t you replace $x$ by $x-a$?

Comment: Ah yes I forgot the I only tested $a = 0$. Thanks.